# Hibernate: is a good practice to set fixed parameters?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

I'm using Java + Hibernate + MariaDB and I have a question about good practices.

If want to execute this query:

```
UPDATE Pics SET views = 0 WHERE id=:id_pic;
```

I use this in my Java code:

```
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
try {           
    tx.begin();

    NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery("UPDATE Pics SET views = 0 WHERE id=:id_pic");
    query.setParameter("id_pic", id_pic);
    result = query.executeUpdate();

    tx.commit();
}
// Exceptions stuff...
```

As you can see, I use the id_pic parameter to avoid security problems. My question is that if I should use parameters when I'm using **fixed variables** like the 0 that appears in the query (it will always have to be a 0, it's a reset method). I mean, should I have to use the following query or the one above?:

```
NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery("UPDATE Pics SET views=:views WHERE id=:id_pic");
query.setParameter("id_pic", id_pic);
query.setParameter("views", String.valueOf(0));
result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "views" it will always be 0, i would say that the first version is more correct. It fits better the purpose. No worries about the fact that the 0 is hardcoded: it is not supposed to change.

That said, if in the future you need to interact also with the column "views" as a dynamic parameter, i woud create **another** query, to which i would pass both columns as parameter

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to use parameters because you have several advantages like:

- You do not need to worry about SQL injection
- The persistence provider maps your query parameters to the correct types
- The persistence provider can do internal optimizations to provide a better performance.

Plus is more easy to maintain and if you want to generate a more generalist *update* method could make sense to use two parameters because maybe in the future you may have the need to update a concrete pic with a view value different from 0 (ZERO).

Hope it helps.